# HOW to Calculate the average speed using gps in ios

Tags: ios, gps

I am using the PSLocationManager API to calculate the average speed of the moving vehicle. But it is not giving me correct speed . Sometime in idle state , it gives higher speed.

In my app , my trip need to be started if my avg speed is greater than 5 miles/hr . So because of this sometime it start in idle state .

Could anybody help me out in this ...I will be thankful to you people..

Comment: I have a smiliar problem, when the device stand still at a red light traffic signal, apple s location manager detects this stand still situation, and does not update anymore the locations, but it keeps the speed value and often does not update to speed = 0;

Comment: But I am not using the speed  parameter of CCLocation , I am calculating the speed based on the distance and time.. You can create a collection of speeds , and then calculate the average speed and use that to avoid this situation.

Comment: yes, in this case that helps, in all other the speed param is more acurate

Comment: is kPrioritizeFasterSpeeds set to NO?